# Postgres 9.3 - Limit value (based on value in different table with foreign key)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "schema"."TableOne" (
    "TableOneID" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "TimeRange" TSTZRANGE
);

CREATE TABLE "schema"."TableTwo" (
    "TableTwoID" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "TableOneID" INTEGER FOREIGN KEY ("SoulID") REFERENCES "schema"."TableOne" ("TableOneID")
    "TimeRange" TSTZRANGE
);
```

I want to make sure that any value in `"TableTwo"."TimeRange"` is contained by the range in `"TableOne"."TimeRange"` where `"TableOne"."TableOneID" = "TableTwo"."TableOneID"`

I have read the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html) (8.17.10. Constraints on Ranges) several times and can't find a way to make this happen... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't yet do that in PostgreSQL. The [pgsql-hackers listserv](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1365459744.68352.YahooMailNeo@web162902.mail.bf1.yahoo.com) recommends using serializable transactions to change data, and using triggers to implement the constraints.